# Spring Boot 1.4 deployment on Openshift v2 :: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/SessionIdGenerator

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, openshift

While deploying my Spring Boot appliction on Openshift v2 I keep on getting this error. Locally within IntelliJ the application is working fine.

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/**SessionIdGenerator**

**Edit:** 
Was this a Spring Boot version issue? Answer: yes. See below.

**Edit 2: **
A solution was to use the Spring Boot 1.3.6 version. 
A **BETTER** solution is to add the  in the  section of the pom.xml. See below.

This is the stacktrace:

```
remote: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/SessionIdGenerator
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
...
```

This is the pom.xml file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>johan974rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>johan974rest</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <!-- Use parent POM.xml -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For data access and JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>nl.xyz.springbootcellar.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.9</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better answer allows you to use the Spring Boot 1.4 !!!

Just add this to your POM.xml file:

```
<build>
    <!-- ADDED/start ... -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- ADDED/end ... -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

After narrowing down the issue, I found that the issue is the Spring Boot version.

This works:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

And changing 1.3.6 to 1.4.2 gives the SessionIdGenerator issue. 
It is not important whether  is used or not.